# Mysql database getting error: #1286 - Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Tags: php, mysql

In our MySql(ver.5.5)[screenshot attached] database some table showing *'in use'* with error

> #1286 - Unknown storage engine InnoDB

and we are unable to open it.

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you messed with any configs lately? Sounds like the InnoDB is disabled or missing entirely.

Comment: Check this topic - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36625/1286-unknown-storage-engine-innodb